# VBA macro how to click on button on website on chrome, using Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to program to click on one button on website on chrome. The name of the button is "Add to Cart".

Please see HTML of the website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWXiZ.png)

And this is the VBA code:

```
CD.FindElementByCss("div.addToCartButtons clearAfter > button blue right s-addToCart > span.Add to Cart").Click
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your HTML as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are important, you can anticipate some of the events attached to certain element in DOM just by reading its tag.

In your case you can click on the **button** tag directly instead of clicking the tag **span**, since this last one rarely has a `.click` event attached to it.

If you can provide an url to test this website I might help you better. This are the possible approaches:

> ```
> 1) Advanced: 
>     a. Spaces in class are change for dots
>     b. Requires to understand tag's meaning and relative position of elements in DOM
> ```

```
        'Example
        'Clicking first button in div using only tag ("button" is a tag)
         CD.FindElementByCss("div.addToCartButtons.clearAfter > button").Click
```

> ```
> 2) Intermedium:
>     a. Use only first Class and ignore all others after first space
>     b. Requires to understand what an elemment.child is
> ```

```
        'Example:
        'Clicking first child of "div" (Everything inside "div" is a child)
         CD.FindElementByCss("div.addToCartButtons > button:nth-child(1)").Click
```

> ```
> 3) Easiest:
>     a. Double quotes ["] inside querySelector are changed to single quote [']
>     b. Requires to use Copy JS path in DevTools (Ctrl + Shif + I)
> ```

```
        'Example:
        'Clicking with Javascript in your website through ExecuteScript 
         strTemp = "document.querySelector('div.addToCartButtons clearAfter > button blue right s-addToCart').click"
         CD.ExecuteScript (strTemp)
```